# Moving from one test to multiple final environments

Tags: directory, migration, multi-language

I'm working on a WordPress website in the following test environment URL:

```
www.example.com/wordpress.
```

Once the site is complete and everything is tested, I want to deploy to three live environments in different languages:

- `www.example.com/nl`
- `www.example.com/fr`
- `www.example.com/en`

My concern: what if I just copy everything from `/wordpress` to `/en`? I know all links will be broken, and also know how to fix this with [this tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

But what if I, let's say, copy everything from `/wordpress` to `/fr` and `/nl` and delete all the pages in order to rebuild them in the correct language? What about the page id's, and the database? Is this a "safe" way to do such a thing, or are there easier methods?

Comment: have you looked in to created a WordPress network of sites? http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Or using a [multilanguage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/)?

Comment: @brasofilo A multilanguage plugin! Of course. I always forget the easiest solutions... Got any suggestions? qTranslate doesn't seem to work well with the latest version of Wordpress.

Comment: My previous comment contains 2 suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is duplicating content to translate a site, it's better to let a plugin do it, or build your own plugin to deal with it.

There are not many of them, and I can cite +WPML, +Multilangual Press and -qTranslate.

*Related posts:*

- *[How to change menu according to the language?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77220/12615)*
- *[How to setcookie if is_page('page') ? should I use add_action('init') or there is another action?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113662/12615)*