# How to change menu according to the language?

Tags: menus, multi-language

I want to change primary menu according to the language of the user. I have reviewed multi language plugins such as WPML and qTranslate. They have lots of features but what I want is much simpler than what they provide.

There will be three links such as English, Arabic, and Turkish in the upper right corner. When the user clicks one of them, the menu bar should change accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via cookies.
We set it with Javascript, reload the page and display different menus in PHP using its value.

First, print the script at the site footer (see comments).
*Note: would be better to enqueue this together with your theme scripts.*

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_77220_language_cookie' );   
/**
 * Cookie script based on http://github.com/bainternet/Admin-Page-Class
 */
function wpse_77220_language_cookie()
{
    echo '<script>
    /* Set Cookie */
    function setCookie( name,value,days ) 
    {
        if (days) 
        {
            var date = new Date(); 
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";

        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    } 

    /* Get Cookie - not used in this example */
    function getCookie( name ) 
    {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";

        var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i]; 
            while (c.charAt(0)==\' \') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* Erase Cookie - not used in this example */
    function eraseCookie(name) { setCookie(name,"",-1); }

    // Bind click on language menu action to show the nav menu.
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        jQuery(".lingo").bind("click", function(event)
        {
            setCookie( "user_lingo", jQuery(this).attr("id") );
        });
    });
</script>
';
}
```

If jQuery is not included in your theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_77220_enqueue_jquery' );   
function wpse_77220_enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Then, in the theme `header.php`, we put this:

```
</head>
<?php 
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['user_lingo'] ) ) {
        $user_lingo = $_COOKIE['user_lingo'];
    } else {
        $user_lingo = 'en';
    }
?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then, the `wp_nav_menu`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $user_lingo ) ); ?>
```

In this example, the navigation menus have the same name of the values we'll set for the cookie. If your menus have another name, you have to adapt the header conditional for `$user_lingo`.
[image: navigation menus]

Finally, the language menu. The class `lingo` is binded via jQuery to set the cookie value with the anchors `id`'s. The `href` value forces the page to reload, you can use another method if you wish.

```
<a href="?lang=pt" id="pt" class="lingo">pt</a> |
<a href="?lang=es" id="es" class="lingo">es</a> |
<a href="?lang=en" id="en" class="lingo">en</a>
```